# Can you dual wield lances?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, weapons, mounted-combat

If you have the dual wielder feat, and you are riding a mount can you wield two lances. Also what would the damage dice be?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, you can.

> Also, a lance requires
>   two hands to wield when you aren’t mounted.

So as long as you *are* mounted, you can use a lance in one hand. The Dual Wielder feat allows you to use two-weapon fighting with any one-handed melee weapon, so this works fine.

As for the damage die, the damage die for the lance is a d12, and there's nothing in its special property or in the dual-wielding rules that would change this.

Comment: Though this question is old, it's intriguing. given that lances are actually heavy poles made to look like swords, would you give a disadvantage to defense in this case? given that the mass of the weapons and your lack of upper body stability would make you more prone to be thrown?

Comment: @VictorB I wouldn't - I'm not a believer in nerfing mundane characters for the sake of "realism".

Answer (score -4):

If you were riding a standard horse, as a DM I might have some qualms about you using dual lances. But a paladin with his own Find Steeed horse could telepathically control its movements, therefore I would allow it.